# Bootstrap method for mixed glm zero-inflated model

Tags: r, mixed-models, glmmtmb

I'd like to bootstrap a mixed glm zero-inflated model (`m_F`) using the `glmmTMB` package, but despite the use of `coef` or `fixef` for coefficients specification, I always have as output the error:

```
Error in bres[i, ] <- coef(bfit) : 
  incorrect number of subscripts on matrix
```

My example:

```
library(glmmTMB)
library(boot)
my.ds <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Leprechault/trash/main/ds.desenvol.csv")
str(my.ds)
# 'data.frame': 400 obs. of  4 variables:
#  $ temp       : num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
#  $ storage    : int  5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 ...
#  $ rep        : chr  "r1" "r2" "r3" "r4" ...
#  $ development: int  0 23 22 27 24 25 24 22 0 22 ...

# Fit a GLM mixed Hurdle (zero-inflated) log-link Gamma model
m_F <- glmmTMB(development ~ poly(temp,2) + (1 | storage), data = my.ds,
               family = ziGamma(link = "log"),
               ziformula = ~ 1)
summary(m_F)

# Create a bootstrap aproach
nboot <- 1000
bres <- matrix(NA,nrow=nboot,
                  ncol=length(coef(m_F)),
                  dimnames=list(rep=seq(nboot),
                                coef=names(coef(m_F))))
set.seed(1000)
bootsize <- 100
for (i in seq(nboot)) {
  bdat <- my.ds[sample(nrow(my.ds),size=bootsize,replace=TRUE),]
  bfit <- update(m_F, data=bdat)  ## refit with new data
  bres[i,] <- coef(bfit)
}
```

Please, any help wit it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My answer is somewhat similar to @RuiBarradas's, but closer to your original code.  The main point is that `coef()` doesn't do what you think; (1) the convention (set originally by the `nlme` package) is that for mixed models `coef()` returns a matrix (or list of matrices) of group-level coefficients, while `fixef()` returns the fixed-effect (population-level) coefficients; (2) for `glmmTMB`, `fixef()` returns a *list* of fixed-effect vectors for the conditional, zero-inflation, and dispersion models (`unlist()` collapses this back to a vector with concatenated names).

The other point to keep in mind is that bootstrapping at the level of individual observations may not be sensible for a data set with grouping structure (you can bootstrap at the group level, or the within-group level, or both; you can bootstrap residuals (if you have a linear model - this won't work for GLMMs with count data); you can also use `lme4::bootMer` to do parametric bootstrapping, which is pretty much the only alternative when you have GLMMs with crossed random effects).

PS  what is `bootsize` doing here?  The standard approach to bootstrapping is to resample a data set *the same size as the original* with replacement.  Resampling only a quarter of the data set (`nrow(my.ds) == 400`, `bootsize == 100`) is well-defined but very unusual — are you doing some particular non-standard kind of bootstrap on purpose ... ?

```r
sum_fun <- function(fit) {
    unlist(fixef(fit))
}

bres <- matrix(NA,
               nrow=nboot,
               ncol=length(sum_fun(m_F)),
               dimnames=list(rep=seq(nboot),
                             coef=names(sum_fun(m_F))))
set.seed(1000)
bootsize <- 100
pb <- txtProgressBar(max = bootsize, style = 3)
for (i in seq(nboot)) {
    setTxtProgressBar(pb, i)
    bdat <- my.ds[sample(nrow(my.ds), size=bootsize,replace=TRUE),]
    bfit <- update(m_F, data=bdat)  ## refit with new data
    bres[i,] <- sum_fun(bfit)
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much @Ben!! The use of a quarter of the data was just only for comparison and for the final model the whole data was used.

Comment: OK.  If I wanted to speed up the example I would probably just make `nboot` smaller -- less confusing.

Answer (score 3):

To use package `boot`, you must define a function that bootstraps the data and then computes the statistic or vector of statistics from it. This is function `ziboot` below. Then call `boot` passing it the data, the function and the number of replicates.

The function fits the same model as the question's code but must transform the model output in a vector of coefficients. That is what the `lapply` does.

```r
library(glmmTMB)
library(boot)

my.ds <- read.csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Leprechault/trash/main/ds.desenvol.csv")

# Create a bootstrap aproach
# This function will be called by boot() below
ziboot <- function(data, i) {
  # this bootstraps the data
  d <- data[i, ]
  model <- glmmTMB(development ~ temp + (1 | storage), data = d,
                 family = ziGamma(link = "log"),
                 ziformula = ~ 1)
  cf <- coef(model)$cond$storage
  l <- as.list(cf)
  unlist(lapply(seq_along(l), \(i){
    x <- l[[i]]
    nms <- paste(names(l)[i], row.names(cf), sep = "_")
    setNames(x, nms)
  }))
}

set.seed(1000)
bootsize <- 100
b <- boot(my.ds, ziboot, R = bootsize)
colnames(b$t) <- names(b$t0)
head(b$t)
#>      (Intercept)_5 (Intercept)_10 (Intercept)_15 (Intercept)_20 (Intercept)_30
#> [1,]      3.156717       3.153949       3.139001       3.147799       3.196308
#> [2,]      3.172563       3.157384       3.164663       3.143005       3.196966
#> [3,]      3.175124       3.154946       3.158715       3.129027       3.168753
#> [4,]      3.149817       3.143550       3.135256       3.141367       3.167679
#> [5,]      3.159183       3.179388       3.147193       3.148219       3.237395
#> [6,]      3.148815       3.168335       3.117576       3.126973       3.178377
#>            temp_5      temp_10      temp_15      temp_20      temp_30
#> [1,] -0.004089067 -0.004089067 -0.004089067 -0.004089067 -0.004089067
#> [2,] -0.004404738 -0.004404738 -0.004404738 -0.004404738 -0.004404738
#> [3,] -0.003153053 -0.003153053 -0.003153053 -0.003153053 -0.003153053
#> [4,] -0.003547863 -0.003547863 -0.003547863 -0.003547863 -0.003547863
#> [5,] -0.003989763 -0.003989763 -0.003989763 -0.003989763 -0.003989763
#> [6,] -0.003137722 -0.003137722 -0.003137722 -0.003137722 -0.003137722
```

<sup>Created on 2022-07-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>